# \r not displaying expected output in the browser console

Tags: javascript, html, string, console, liveserver

\r not displaying expected output in the browser console

```
let need= 'n000000000000000\rjjjjjj'  
    console.log(need)  //expected output :jjjjjj0000000000 but I'm getting n000000000000000jjjjjj
```

but I'm getting expected output in replit
[image: code used in vs code and opened in browser using live server]
[image: output showed in browser console]

replit code and output

[image: code added in replit website to test my code]
[image: output got in replit console]

Comment: browser console doesn't treat `\r` as "carriage return" like  regular "console"

Comment: The browser console isn't a terminal.

Comment: So how can I get output in the browser same as the terminal?